# Running a command in screen daemon mode

Tags: bash, screen, sed

I am trying to run a command in screen mode using the command

```
screen -dmS screen_name sed -i 's/a/b/'g some-file.txt
```

Nothing happens. When I put the same command in a script and run the command:

```
screen -dmS screen_name bash -c /path/to/script
```

It works.
My question is, can I run a command in daemon mode without first having to put it in a script?
Basically, I need this daemon feature because it helps in running several commands in parallel, by running several sed commands on large files in parallel by throwing each command on a separate screen daemon, which terminates automatically after the program finishes.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the issue is with the -S if you try to omit the -S option, it should ,work, even without bash -c
so try this

```
screen -dm sed -i 's/a/b/'g some-file.txt
```

That should work. 
BTW screen is not updated, you should consider switching to tmux. It can provide you with much more features.

You can install tmux by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install tmux
```

So your code should look like:

```
tmux new-session -d -s foo 'sed -i 's/a/b/'g some-file.txt'
```

I could test it with

```
tmux new-session -d -s hello 'top'
```

if you type

```
tmux attach -t hello
```

It will take you to a session with top. Hope that this helps. check

```
man tmux
```

for all features
and check [here](https://gist.github.com/MohamedAlaa/2961058) for a comprehensive cheat sheet

Comment: Screen is updated nowadays. http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
screen -dmS screen_name bash -c "sed -i 's/a/b/'g some-file.txt"
```

Comment: I tried with single quotes, and double quotes, no luck :(

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to run such a command inside of screen?

Comment: I am editing huge files with sed in order to replace some special characters. Sed usually runs using one processor, which could take hours. Running in daemon mode enables several commands to run in parallel.

Comment: If you just want to achieve backgrounding: Use a single ampersand at the end of your command. Run the sed command within a screen session with an ampersand to not bind the processes on your session. Then use the command `jobs` to view running tasks.

Comment: I see where you are going with this, but that wouldn't work inside a script.

Comment: It will if you `nohup` it.  But then it won't be accessible via `jobs` - it will truly daemonize.

Comment: I just tested my solution and for me it seems to work:   
`cat some-file.txt 
f
ff
fff
; screen -dmS screen_name bash -c "sed -i 's/f/g/'g some-file.txt"
; cat some-file.txt 
g
gg
ggg`